# Change font of a spied-on plot

Tags: pgfplots, spy

I have a simple plot and I have to change the font, the color in this occasion, of the text (title, axis labels, ticks labels...). I'd put something like `font=\color{red}` as an option of the `tikzpicture` and everything goes great. If I now add a `spy scope`, the font does not change, even without actually calling `\spy`.

I have tried to add some options to `axis` (`font=\color{red}`, `tick label style=...`, `label style=...`) but that didn't seem to work.

I guess what's happening there is that `spy` is re-drawing the plot. So, I also tried to pass those options to `spy` but I couldn't make it work.

I attach a MWE and the results with and without using `spy`.

```latex
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  font=\color{red},
  % Uncomment next line for the problem
  %spy scope={spy using outlines,circle,magnification=2,connect spies,}
  ]
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis line style={color=red},
    xlabel={Deg},
    ylabel={$\sin(x)$},
    title={Title},
    ]
    \addplot[blue] expression[domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: without spy]

[image: with spy]

Comment: `spy` explicitly resets the color. https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/15c943b7a5774c58e45390acdddd36e9f4260607/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryspy.code.tex#L67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spy` explicitly resets a couple of drawing options using the [`tikz@lib@reset@gs`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/15c943b7a5774c58e45390acdddd36e9f4260607/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryspy.code.tex#L67) key.  It has been like that since the `spy` library was introduced.  There is also an open issues complaining about this:

> https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/334

If you don't like the color resetting option, just remove it from the reset list.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{
  tikz@lib@reset@gs/.style={
    %black,
    thin,
    solid,
    opaque,
    line cap=butt,
    line join=miter,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  font=\color{red},
  % Uncomment next line for the problem
  spy scope={spy using outlines,circle,magnification=2,connect spies,}
  ]
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis line style={color=red},
    xlabel={Deg},
    ylabel={$\sin(x)$},
    title={Title},
    ]
    \addplot[blue] expression[domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```